# Scatterplot colors lost when converting to plotly in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, plotly, visualization

I'm trying to build a bubbleplot with, for example, the following data:

```
    # install.packages("tidyverse")
    # install.packages("plotly")
    # install.packages("viridis")

    library(tidyverse)
    library(plotly) 
    library(viridis) 

    data <- tribble(
    ~race, ~gender, ~count, 
    "race1", "gender1", 15, 
    "race1", "gender2", 58,
    "race1", "gender3", 59,
    "race2", "gender1", 100,
    "race2", "gender2", 12,
    "race2", "gender3", 13, 
    "race3", "gender1", 14, 
    "race3", "gender2", 39, 
    "race3", "gender3", 87
    )
```

When I run a ggplot command to create a colored scatterplot, I get more or less what I want (code and figure below):

```
bubble <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = race, y = gender)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = log10(count) * 4, fill = count), shape = 21) + 
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = F) +
  geom_text(aes(label = count), size = 4) +
  scale_size_identity() +
  xlab("Race") + 
  ylab("Gender") + 
  theme_classic()
```

[Image of bubble plot, colored by count variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgkCs.png)

However, when I use the following command to convert this plot to an interactive plotly graph, I lose the color distinction (see figure below). I've scratched my head over this for a while now, and can't seem to find a solution to the problem...Plotly seems to retain color distinction for other types of graphs I've made (e.g. bar charts).

I also get the attached warning message:

```
ggplotly(bubble)

> Warning message:
In L$marker$color[idx] <- aes2plotly(data, params, "fill")[idx] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

[Plotly version of the same graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk5Sd.png)

Does anyone have an idea of what is going on / how to retain the "fill" coloring I indicated in the original ggplot graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some troubleshooting, it seems to be your call to `shape = 21` in `geom_point`.  Try this workaround instead:

```
bubble <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = race, y = gender)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = log10(count) * 4, color = count)) + 
  scale_color_viridis(discrete = F) +
  geom_text(aes(label = count), size = 4) +
  scale_size_identity() +
  xlab("Race") + 
  ylab("Gender") + 
  theme_classic()

ggplotly(bubble)
```

Note: you'll have to change all your `fill` calls to `color` (including `scale_color_viridis`)

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't have thought that was the problem! Thank you so much, this worked perfectly.